# How to Add Link with custom template in Magento 2.1?

Tags: customer, theme, magento-2.1, navigation, link

I want to make a custom navigation for my theme, I'm overriding navigation.phtml template from Magento_Customer but I realized the links are made it by layout and they always return the link wrapped inside one li element. I'm calling my custom template but I don't know how to get only the link. This is how I'm creating the link:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link" template="Magento_Customer::account/menulink.phtml">
   <arguments>
     <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Dashboard</argument>
     <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
   </arguments>
</block>
```

How magento return link

```
<li class="nav item"><a href="http://testshop.io/customer/account/edit/">Account Information</a></li>
```

How I want to have it

```
<a href="http://testshop.io/customer/account/edit/"><h4><i class="fa fa-icon"></i><br/><span>Account Information</span></a>
```

Any idea of how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically I realized that you could sent arguments to your template and using the method $block->getHref() from the class  Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current you could get the link. With this you just have to add a template to the block in your layout and use all the arguments in your template, like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link" template="Magento_Customer::account/menulink.phtml">
   <arguments>
     <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Dashboard</argument>
     <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
     <argument name="icon" xsi:type="string">user</argument>
   </arguments>
</block>
```

and in your layout like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->getHref() ?>" class="list-group-item active text-center">
    <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-<?php echo $block->getIcon() ?>"></h4><br/><?php echo $block->getLabel() ?>
</a>
```

Hope somebody found this helpful.